# Is there such an adjective as "neugiererzeugend"?

Tags: vocabulary

is there an adjective that describes something that arouses curiosity, like for example, when you see an ad that gets you curious about the product?
I instinctively thought it could be "neugiererzeugend", but unfortunately Google and German spell-check beg to differ :/

Comment: Don't worry, "neugiererzeugend" isn't wrong grammatically (it properly follows word-building rules and catches exactly the meaning you intended) - it's just that (almost) noone used it so far, so it might sound a little odd to people.

Comment: I guess, the boring but well-established German word is simply *interessant* (interesting), which could be further extended to *Interesse weckend* (arousing interest).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constructed term would be

> neugiererregend / Neugier erregend

The combination of noun *»neugier«* and *»erregend«* (present participle of *»[erregen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/erregen)«*) is not (yet?) part of the dictionary, these e. g. are:

> [aufsehenerregend](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/aufsehenerregend), [ekelerregend](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/ekelerregend), [furchterregend](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/furchterregend), [krebserregend](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/krebserregend),
>   [schwindelerregend](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/schwindelerregend)

*»neugiererzeugend«* isn't wrong, but unusual.

Related:

- [anziehend](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/anziehend) (*attractive*)
- [verlockend](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/verlockend) (*enticing*)
- [verführerisch](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/verfuehrerisch) (*tempting*)
- [unwiderstehlich](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/unwiderstehlich) (*irresistible*)

Comment: A more common term would be "neugierig machen (making so. curious)".

Comment: @DirkLiebhold: Das Adjektiv _»neugierigmachend«_ wäre dann aber relativ sperrig und auch nicht gebräuchlich.

Comment: Hm. Neugier ist also etwas das sowohl wenn schon existend erregt werden kann (neugiererregend), wie soll es auch erregt werden wenn es nicht existiert, als auch erzeugt werden (neugierig machen). Auch ist die Erzeugung der Neugier und dessen Erregung gleichbedeutend. Ein seltsames Tier diese Neugier. Jetzt möchte ich mehr über sie erfahren :D

Answer (score 0):

"Neugiererzeugend" isn't technically wrong (as a compound) but sounds very odd. I've never seen that word anywhere and no native speaker would ever say that. It sounds very awkward.

In this case, I think the best word would just be "interessant".

Comment: Wenn etwas interessant ist, heißt das aber nicht zwingend, dass man auch neugierig ist. So sind Lotteriegewinne von 100.000 € oder eine anstehende Gehaltsverdopplung interessant, machen aber nicht neugierig, weil man die entscheidenden Fakten schon kennt.